# Crytography.fernet in python invalid token error

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography

I have a problem. I am currently trying to learn encryption types and techniques.
I am writing a python code to encrypt and decrypt a message using the `cryptography.fernet`.

The official docs say that:

> ttl (int) – Optionally, the number of seconds old a message may be for
>   it to be valid. If the message is older than ttl seconds (from the
>   time it was originally created) an exception will be raised. If ttl is
>   not provided (or is None), the age of the message is not considered.

So after a minute when I try to decrypt the encrypted text, it gives me the following error:

Below is my code:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)

cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
print(key)
print(type(key))

with open("key.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(key)

with open("read_plain_text_from_here.txt", "r") as f:
    encoded_text = f.read().encode()
    cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(encoded_text)

with open("write_cipher_text_here.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(cipher_text)

with open("write_cipher_text_here.txt", "rb") as f:
    cipher_text = f.read()

with open("write_plain_text_here.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text, ttl=None))
```

Below is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "---\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 104, in _verify_signature
    h.verify(data[-32:])
  File "---\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hmac.py", line 66, in verify
    ctx.verify(signature)
  File "---\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\hmac.py", line 74, in verify
    raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_encode_2.py", line 22, in <module>
    f.write(cipher_suite.decrypt(cipher_text, ttl=None))
  File "---\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 75, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, ttl)
  File "---\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 117, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "---\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 106, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

**NOTE:** This only happens after I try to decrypt the text after a minute or more. If I run within a minute, it runs smooth.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please include code that demonstrates the problem. It can't possibly be the code you've shown because there is no delay in decryption in it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Thats the complete code. what I am doing is, first I execute the first three filehandlers while commenting out the other two. Then after a minute or more I comment out the first three file handlers then execute the last two. Thats when this error happens

Comment: Well then, how do you get the key?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I have edited the code. I missed the first few line. Sorry. Have a look now.

Comment: It generates a new key every time, so it always give you an error if you restart it and comment out the first three `with` blocks.

Comment: @JamesKPolk It worked. Arrggghhhh... Silly mistake. Might have lost my focus.  Thank a lot though :)